# SQL: Can NOT EXISTS have "OR"?

Tags: sql-server-2016, not-exists

I have a SQL query with NOT EXISTS to exclude a certain set of values from the end result.

```
select distinct 
from [rpt_StockInventorySummary] a
where a.[DepartmentId] ='P'
and not exists (
select *
from rpt_StockInventorySummary b
where b.DepartmentId = 'p' 
and b.Manufacturer = 'warrington'
and b.LowestGroup = 57 and b.Instock = 0
and b.Barcode = a.Barcode
)
order by a.SortOrder
```

The query works just fine, but now I need to modify the SQL so that another set of values is ecluded from the end result. So I tried modifying the SQL inside the NOT EXISTS like this.

```
select *
from rpt_StockInventorySummary b
where b.DepartmentId = 'p' 
and b.Manufacturer = 'warrington'
and (b.LowestGroup = 57 and b.Instock = 0)
or b.LowestGroup = 60
and b.Barcode = a.Barcode
```

By itself, the query runs and returns the values just fine. But when I run the whole query, I get no result. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL has a well defined order of operations. AND clauses are evaluated before OR clauses. As such, your new query will select records where the following is true:

```
b.DepartmentId = 'p' 
and b.Manufacturer = 'warrington'
and (b.LowestGroup = 57 and b.Instock = 0)
```

OR

```
b.LowestGroup = 60
and b.Barcode = a.Barcode
```

I suspect the following will give you what you are looking for:

```
select *
from rpt_StockInventorySummary b
where b.DepartmentId = 'p' 
and b.Manufacturer = 'warrington'
and (b.LowestGroup = 57 and b.Instock = 0 or b.LowestGroup = 60)
and b.Barcode = a.Barcode
```